# Exchanging variables between 2 classes

Tags: c#, polymorphism, subclass, superclass, inheritance

Whenever I call the method Draw in Sprite, it won't draw it because X, Y, Width and Height are 0. :(

code:

```
class Sprite   
{
    protected int Y;// { get; set; }
    protected int X;// { get; set; } { get; set; }
    protected int Width;// { get; set; } { get; set; }
    public int Height;// { get; set; } { get; set; }
    protected Image image;// { get; set; } { get; set; }

    public Sprite()
    {

    }

    public void Draw(Graphics drawArea)
    {
        Image sImage = Image.FromFile("alien.jpg");
        drawArea.Clear(Color.White);
        drawArea.DrawImage(sImage, X, Y, Width, Height);
    }
}

class User:Sprite
{
    public User()
    {

    }

    public User(int width, int height, int userWidth, int userHeight)
    {
        Sprite sprite = new Sprite();
        Image UserImage = Image.FromFile("alien.jpg");

        X = width;
        Y = height;
        Width = userWidth;  
        Height = userHeight;
        image = UserImage;
    }
}
```

ps: sprite.Draw is declared in another method in another class, but that all should work just fine.
Thanks for helping and probably saving me hours of time :)

Nick

**EDIT**

here is the subclass which gives the parameter and other stuff.

```
  Alien mAlien;
User mUser;
protected int mLevel;


public gameLogic()
{


}


public gameLogic(int width, int height, int level)
{
  mUser = new User(width / 2, height - 30, 30, 30);
  mAlien = new Alien(width / 2, 5, 30, 30, "alien.jpg", 10 * level);
  mLevel = level;
}

public void drawAll(Graphics drawArea)
{
  Sprite sprite = new Sprite();
  sprite.Draw(drawArea);
}
```

Im sorry for all these errors that'll probably occur, Im a new student :)

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking for and where the problem is - try improving your question. However the line `Sprite sprite = new Sprite();` in the constructor of `User` derived from `Sprite` looks suspicious.

Comment: The `user` is a dervied class, it does not need its own Sprite property as it is a sprite. so you can removethe `Sprite sprite = new Sprite();` line.  As for the UserImage, it is being assign to your `image` property, although `image` never gets used by your spirte base class.

Can you please add in the code you use to declare a user

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
public User(int width, int height, int userWidth, int userHeight)
{
    Sprite sprite = new Sprite();
    Image UserImage = Image.FromFile("alien.jpg");

    sprite.X = width;
    sprite.Y = height;
    sprite.Width = userWidth;  
    sprite.Height = userHeight;
    sprite.image = UserImage;
}
```

In order to access the fields of the sprite, you have to specify which `Sprite` object you are modifying. This is done by writing the name of the variable followed by `.`

**EDIT:** Just realized that there is another problem - your `User` class is inheriting from the `Sprite` class. Apparently your users **are** sprites, according to the comments, so you'll want to never instantiate a `Sprite`, and just use the `User` class instead:

```
class User:Sprite
{
    public User(int width, int height, int userWidth, int userHeight)
    {
        Image UserImage = Image.FromFile("alien.jpg");

        X = width;
        Y = height;
        Width = userWidth;  
        Height = userHeight;
        image = UserImage;
    }
}
```

Then instead of calling draw on a sprite in the other file, use the following:

```
User user = new User(x, y, width, height)

...

user.draw();
```

The key here is to make sure you are using `new User...` and not `new Sprite` - even if you are assigning to a `Sprite` variable e.g. `Sprite s = new User(...);`.

Then just make sure you call draw on the same object - the `user.draw` line. If you want to check that you're doing it right, try making `Sprite` `abstract` - `abstract class Sprite` - that way there will be compile errors if you try to instantiate `Sprite` instead of `User`.

EDIT 2: Ok, all you really need to do is change your calling code:

```
public void drawAll(Graphics drawArea)
{
    mUser.draw(drawArea);
    mAlien.draw(drawArea);
}
```

Comment: Wow quick reply ! I'm going to try this out tomorow !

Comment: @NickPeelman, Jeff's solution is good. Just make sure you fix your Sprite.Draw() method. your current line: `drawArea.DrawImage(sImage, X, Y, Width, Height);`  should use the `image` property not `sImage`

Comment: Jeff, It doesn't seem to work right now, also i need to inherite from sprite. Our teacher told us to do so :s. But i'll give it a good look tomorow, thanks for your time !

Comment: @NickPeelman Ah, ok, I misunderstood what you were trying to do. I'll update the edit with what you need

Comment: Ye sorry about that, it's not easy to say what i want in another language :)

-EDIT-

The class sprite should just give the methods while User and later on alien will just have to give the parameters, old fashion space invador game !

Comment: @NickPeelman See my second update - it's your calling code that's the problem here - you're just creating a new `Sprite` and drawing it, instead of using the sprites you already made - `User`s and `Alien`s **are** sprites - they *have* the methods. You don't need to go directly to a `Sprite` to get to them.

Answer (score -1):

You are missing trailing '}' for both your classes, Sprite and User. Second you should call the base-Constructor in User's constructor:

```
public User(int width, int height, int userWidth, int userHeight)
     : base(width, height, userWidth, userHeight, Image.FromFile("alien.jpg"))
{
}
```

Also you need to create a constructor for your base class which accepts these parameters.

Comment: Agree with existing downvote: Why OP "need" to create another constructor in base class? There is no particular problem  with assigning values to properties in derived class. Would be nice, but there is no "need" for that.

Comment: @Nick Peelman Don't worry. :> If you need a bit more detailed example I will write one for you. It would be the solution for a User deriving Sprite. The question was a bit unclear and out of source code I interpreted the question like this.